While converting json to pdf unicode characters are replaced
In my API I am getting JSON response from one API, I have to convert it to a PDF and send it.
But while marshalling characters like <, >, & .. are replaced by \u300e,...
Also " within JSON strings get changed to â€œ in PDF.
Currently using "github.com/jung-kurt/gofpdf" for pdf conversion.
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to send HTTP request: %v", err)
    }

        var jsonData map[string]interface{}
    err = json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&jsonData)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to decode JSON response: %v", err)
    }

    // Pretty-print the JSON data
    formattedJSON, err := json.MarshalIndent(jsonData, "", "  ")
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to marshal JSON: %v", err)
    }
    
    jsonStr := string(formattedJSON)
    
        // Initialize the PDF
    pdf := gofpdf.New("P", "mm", "A4", "")
    pdf.AddPage()
    pdf.SetFont("Arial", "", 10)
    
        // Add the formatted JSON content as text
    lineHeight := 4.5
    pdf.SetAutoPageBreak(true, 10)
    pdf.MultiCell(0, lineHeight, jsonStr, "", "", false)
    
        // Write the PDF to a buffer
    var pdfBuf bytes.Buffer
    err = pdf.Output(&pdfBuf)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to write PDF: %v", err)
    }
    w.Header().Set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+strings.Replace(sbomName, ".json", ".pdf", 1))
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/pdf")

    _, err = w.Write(pdfBuf.Bytes())
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to write PDF response: %v", err)
    }

PDF creation is working fine, problem seems to occur while marshalling.

You seem to misunderstand how JSON works and how font handling in PDFs work.
